# How to optimize large computation in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, optimization, arraylist, parallel-processing

I'm developing a function in Android using Java that takes two byte array and do some complex computation, and the byte array come from the database so it will be something like:

```
ArrayList<myModel> myList = new ArrayList<>;
myList = readDataFromDataBase();
```

In the myModel there is a byte[] variable, and once I read all the data from database, I need to process the byte array and do some computation,if the result is met I want it to stop process.

```
for(myModel my : myList){
   byte[] temp;
   temp = my.getByteArray();
   if(computeData(temp)){
     break;
   }
}
```

If I have only few data in the database, the performance is okay, but if I have 1000 data, I got poor performance.

So I've tried using parallel stream.

```
myList.parallelStream.forEach()
```

But it seems like not improving the performance. Also I have tried ExecutorService and still the same. Is there any way I can optimize this? Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: I would imagine that kicking off threads would be more expensive than comparing byte values.  Maybe your `computeData` is very inefficient.  Hard to know as you have not posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use computeData() while reading the arrays, and stop when you need to. So that way you won't be reading the data you don't want and can save some time there. Also the first m in myModel class should be capital according to java conventions. And of course u can try to optimize both the methods

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that using this for loop takes O(n), if the computation goes to the last element in the arraylist it will take massive amount of time. So I am trying to using parallel process to optimize it but not sure how.

Comment: I can't see any possible way to use parallel computing here, u can save a lot of time by not reading all the data.